# What is the best translation of "commodity"?

Tags: traduction

For the English word "commodity" which refers to raw materials which are traded (e.g. metals, energy, food), I have difficulties to find a good French translation. Some dictionaries propose "la matière première", while on the [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodit%C3%A9) it is "commodité". What is the right translation? Are both acceptable?

Related to this question is "commodity price". Is that "le prix des matières premières" or better something like "le prix de commodité"?

Comment: Context matters. If you're writing an economics essay for an economics class or some economics/finance newspaper in French, « commodité » will work; otherwise, look for alternatives!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Wikipedia already explains:

- "Commodity" has no straight translation.
- *Matière première* meaning is narrower than commodity. While coal, copper and oil are definitely *matières premières*, it's much less acceptable for an immaterial thing like electricity, or for something not transformed like bananas.
- *Commodité* is controversial and only used with this meaning by people already familiar with the English "commodity". The traditional meanings of *[commodité](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/commodit%C3%A9)* (that includes "restrooms"!), also [utilities: FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/EQUI49), do not allow to easily understand what is meant by this new acceptation.

The [OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8380719) recommends *[marchandises](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/marchandise)*, also *[biens](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/biens) de consommation*, *[produits](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/produit/1)*, *[articles](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/article)*.

See all the [Termium Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=commodity&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) site that suggests translations for many combination of words using "commodity".

Note that *prix **de** commodités* wouldn't be use even by those comfortable with *commodités*, that would be *prix **des** commodités*.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities seen on [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/commodity.html) :

> - produit de base
> - service de base

less common :

> - produit de consommation

(All those are better than *matières premières* because it can be products that are not raw material such as electricity, basic food etc.)